# How to find out when I got a downvote on an already upvoted or accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

A user accepted my answer but the header shows `+3`  and the dropdown shows `+15`. The original increase in reputation is only `+3` .

- I last checked my profile 8 hours before and there was no negative vote. I also checked now but there are no signs of a negative vote.
- I did not reach the daily max limit of 200 points.

I know if someone downvoted me that would be subtracted from current answer reputation, but is there any way to find out the time of the downvote, and  what question or answer among the already upvoted or accepted answers?
As the other downvote would be visible on my account.

As every downvote has a reputation change of `-2` this means that I get `6` downvotes and `-12` reputation and I can't find that question or answer so that I can improve it.

**Snapshot 1**: Header shows `+3` and on clicking it no sign of downvotes. I only got a +3 reputation increase.

[image]

**Snapshot 2**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the "show removed posts" checkbox checked? (Could also be rep lost from an upvoted answer + approved suggested edit among other things.)

Comment: @Mat Can you tell me where is exactly where that checkbox is.I only found a link `deleted recent questions` but I dont have any deleted question. The reputation `+3` on answered question instead of `+15` says I have `-12` means there are 6 downvotes in 8 hour span then why I cant find `-12` reputation is not less.

Comment: It in your profile, reputation tab, at the bottom left, just above the site footer.

Comment: @Mat thanks that showed me the negative votes.Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it and It would be easy for other to find the solution.